# Checking Permutation for int array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static boolean isPermutation(int[] listA, int[] listB)
{
    if (listA == null || listB == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Violation of precondition: " + "isPermutation. neither parameter may equal null.");

    if (listA.length == listB.length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < listA.length; j++)
            {
                if (listA[i] ==  listB[j])
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am writing a function which checks for permutation between the two array list. Permutation, for example, are {2,2,1} where the unique permutations can be {2,1,2} , {1,2,2} and {2,2,1}. {2,2} is not a unique permutation. It took me some time to write this code and want to know if its right and if someone can explain a better method of doing it? Also, I am told to do this using basic array functions so no hashmaps, ArrayList, etc.

Comment: You should be able to determine if it's right yourself. Write some unit tests, pass in known good and bad inputs and verify the results are as you expect them.

Comment: I did do it and it passed 5 of the tests. I am wondering how the true statement works. I am new to programming so this might be a very stupid question. Would the function return true immediately if the condition satisfies or would it iterate till the end of the first loop and check if every value if true.

Comment: A `return` statement causes a return from the method as soon as it is executed.

Comment: It sounds like you think you may see a flaw in your program.  In that case, consider what inputs would be required to make the flaw manifest as incorrect behavior, and add such a case to your test suite.

Comment: Do you think I should store the value as a boolean and then return the value?

Comment: The issue here is that knowing that they have a particular value in common does not mean that they are permutations. Rather, knowing that there is a value that they don't share mean that they are *not* permutations, so in that case you could immediately return false.

Comment: I tried doing it by your way but it doesn't work for 2 of the 15 test cases I have. I think my logic about this is wrong. Do you think sorting both the arrays in ascending or descending order and then comparing them would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't work. All you are checking is that the lists have the same length and have at least one value in common (as mentioned before, `return true` will immediately exit the function). So e.g. [1,2,3] and [3,4,5] will be returned as being permutations.

The right approach here is to sort both arrays, then compare them position-by-position. This is not only more efficient than looping over both arrays, but also handles duplicate values properly. E.g. [1,2,2] and [1,1,2] are *not* permutations of each other.

Comment: I did try it for the example you gave and it results in false. But you do seem to have a valid explanation. I'll try sorting them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong and will not check if one array is permutation of other or not. You can find the right approach [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-arrays-are-permutations-of-each-other/). The simple solution in the link provides you the method by basic array operations i.e by sorting the arrays while the better one uses hashing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a hashmap. Do you think sorting both the arrays and then comparing them would work?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Take a few examples whenever you are in confusion. Say, you want to check  for  [1,3,2,5,3,4] and [3,2,5,3,4,1] which you can see clearly are permutations of each other. Now sort both of them, as they contain same elements same number of times, their sorted order would be same i.e. [1,2,3,3,4,5] and hence the result.